# Best way too View lots of files on a web page | wordpress, html

Tags: php, html, documentation, wordpress

I am planning a website that will have a page that will have lots of information e.g. pdf's , docs.
for the user too browse and download(on the page(no login) ).

**Note**
currently it has a long list of links that point too a PDFs..(200 links).
will be doing this in WordPress.

**Question**
What is the best way too do this or WordPress plugin ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some plugins that will list files from folders.

[List Yo Files Pro](http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-yo-files/) seems popular and sounds like it fits your requirements.

Description from WP plugin directory.

> Allows users to easily display lists of files in their pages and
>   posts. Supply the folder and various options and you can generate a
>   list of files with hyperlinks to each file making it downloadable.
>   Extensive options let you sort and filter files. You can include file
>   size, date, and even an icon as part of the file list. You can even
>   display lists of MP3s in popular audio players. The plugin admin pages
>   also allow you to conveniently upload and delete files. This is a easy
>   way for organizations, groups, and clubs to share files with members.
>   For example, Home Owner Associations have used this plugin to list
>   their minutes. Music websites use this plugin to allow their users to
>   show off their music.